# Filtro webservice produtos magento

Tags: web-service, magento

Olá, eu estou trabalhando em um `webservice` que lista todos os produtos da minha loja e gostaria de definir um filtro que retorne apenas os produtos que têm qtde no estoque, como posso fazer isso?

abaixo estão os meus códigos de como eu estou fazendo :

```
$sessionId = $client->login('username','api_key');  
$funcoes = $client->resources($sessionId);
$result = $client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.list');
```

Eu preciso de algum filtro para retornar apenas os produtos que têm em estoque, obrigado.

Comment: Precisa ver se o magento já tem algo pronto ou implementar uma consulta na base que verifique se o campo `qtd` é maior que zero, essa parte da implementação é a do 'server'.

Comment: booa @rray ... acabei de fazer isso kkkk obrigado por responder